# How to vertically center text in multi-lined TextView using Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a TextView with 3 lines. I have added constraints as shown in the image.

Code for which is:

```
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:lines="3"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I want the text to start from center of a textView but it's starting from top how can I fix this?

**SEE IMAGE [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhmMQ.jpg)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `android:gravity="center"` to your Textview
 like below :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:lines="3"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: My upvote will not show in public as I am low ranked it says. Marked as answer . I thought there is no need to touch XML while using constraint layout.